# I want to change the combo box of the shopping cart page into a text box

Tags: php

Current page

[image: screenshot]

Code

```
$body .= 'select name="number" id="';
        $body .= $row["ID"] . '" onchange="changeNumber( this );"  >';
        //
        $qty = (int) $row["quantity"];
        for ($number = 0; $number <= 10; $number++) {
            $body .= '<option ';
            if ($number == $qty) {
                $body .= ' selected value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>';
            } else {
                $body .= ' value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>';
            }
        }
        $body .= /select>';
```

Comment: the combo box consists of `<select><option>` tags, if you want a text box just take that out and replace it into `<input type="text"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$body .= '<select name="number" id="'.$row["ID"] .'" onchange="changeNumber( this );" >';
        $qty = (int) $row["quantity"];
        for ($number = 0; $number <= 10; $number++) {
            $selected = '';
            if($number == $qty) {
                $selected = "selected";
            }
            $body .= '<option '.$selected.' value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>';
        }
        $body .= '</select>';
```